# How to generate a random number a certain percentage of time

Tags: java, arrays, math, random

I am trying to generate a random number that only populates a certain percent of the time.  For example, I want to create an array that is set between a certain range (lets say 0-100), but 10% of the time I want the random number chosen to be multiplied by n.  How would I be able to generate this "random" number n% of the time?

*edit*
I haven't tried it yet in Java, I've only been trying to write out the algorithm by hand but I am just getting stumped.  What I am going to have is a variable that holds a number, lets say that number is 3000, and the random number from the array is going to be deducted out of the number 3000 until it hits 0, but a certain percent of the time I want the number pulled from the array to be multiplied by n a certain percent of the time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something 10% of the time by picking a random number between 0 and 100 and triggering the event if the number is less than 10.  So, pick your random number.  Then choose another random number between 0 and 100 and if that second number is less than 10, you multiply the first by n.

Comment: Although to get 10% of the time you can better take an random number between 0 and 10, and see if it is 0

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static boolean getRandPercent(int percent) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(100) <= percent;
}
```